Testing Blazor element's CSS using bUnit and AngleSharp
I'm trying to write unit tests for the Blazor components of my application. So far, I have been using bUnit to test the contents of the component, but I also need to test that the correct CSS stylings have been applied. Since bUnit uses some Anglesharp code and has access to functions like ComputeCurrentStyle(), it seems like using it should be possible.
What would be the correct way of attaching the style sheets to the components I'm testing? Assuming I have access to an IRenderedFragment and thus any 'IElements' that can be found from it.
Documentation for Anglesharp tests checking CSS have relied on using an IBrowsingContext to load an IDocument using an URL, with the CSS being provided by the IConfiguration. Since I am trying to test individual components, I'm not sure how this works in conjunction with IRenderedFragments. Anglesharp is brand new to me so any help would be appreciated.
Edit: I have since been able to load the RenderFragment into a HtmlDocument by using _context.OpenAsync(r => r.Content(detailsComponent.Markup));. From here, I can get the IElements and call ComputedStyle on them. However, the style sheets are not applying the stylesheets I'm expecting. Is this a limitation of getting the HtmlDocument through the Markup?
